# App submission with app not deployable on iOS 6 possible now?

Tags: iphone, app-store, submission

My app is ready for the latest iOS version available to the consumers. Now that iOS 6 apps are being accepted, is it mandatory for me to make my app deployable on iOS 6? Or can I specify that the app runs on iOS 5.1.1 only and still submit? Will doing so cause a rejection saying that iOS 6 needs to be supported?

Comment: hey I have the similar case, does ur app accepted to app store or ios 6 compatibility is mandatory ?

Comment: Why is this marked as off-topic?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can only specify a minimal iOS Version, not a maximum version.
2. just submit it, if you don't want to spend some time making it iOS 6 screen aware

Answer (score -1):

You can submit Apps that you compile with Xcode 4.4.1, they will run on iOS 6 but in a letterbox mode. It will be accepted.

But I recommend to adopt it to iOS 6. It took me only 2 hours to upgrade one of my Apps for iOS 6. This, explains the procedure: [Developing fullscreen 4inch app in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402803/developing-fullscreen-4inch-app-in-xcode/12402922#12402922)