# Developing fullscreen 4inch app in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I support the taller iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397811/how-do-i-support-the-taller-iphone-5-screen-size)

How to make my app 4inch-ready? My app in iOS6GM simulator looks not 4inch-sized.
Is there any option in xcode to use all 4 inches?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Some users have reported that it was fixed after adding the startup image `Default-568h@2x.png` (see below).
For updating to iPhone5 I did the following:

Autorotation is changing in iOS 6. In iOS 6, the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method of UIViewController is deprecated. In its place, you should use the `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` and `shouldAutorotate` methods. Thus, I added these new methods (and kept the old for iOS 5 compatibility):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;    
}
```

- Then I fixed the autolayout for views that needed it.
- Copied images from the simulator for startup view and views for the
  iTunes store into PhotoShop and exported them as png files.
- The name of the default image is: Default-568h@2x.png the size is
  640 x 1136 and the screen size 320 x 568.
- I have dropped backward compatibility for iOS 4. The reason is that
  this new Xcode does not support armv6 code any more. Thus, all
  devices that I am able to support now (running armv7) can be upgraded
  to iOS 5.

That was all but just remember to test the autorotation in iOS 5 and iOS 6 because of the changes in rotation.

Comment: Removing the splash screen images, cleaning the project and readding the splash screen images solved it for me! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Before iPhone 5 release, I just use

```
#define kViewHeight 460.f // or 480.f if you don't have a status bar
#define kViewWidth  320.f
```

But now, I would like to use

```
#define kViewHeight CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame)
#define kViewWidth  CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame)
```

instead.

But I'm not sure whether it is a good solution. As you see, you would dispatch `CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame)` every where you use `kViewHeight`. I've tried to use

```
extern float kViewHeight; // in .h
float kViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame) // in .m
```

but failed with a compile error.

Though it works well, I think there must be a better workaround. ;)

Comment: I don't think that using CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame) every time will cause any performance issues

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu Thanks for your reply! I've not tested the performance yet. And yes, I think it might not leads much performance problem, that's why I put it here as an answer. ;)