# Tabbar not Resizing with iPhone-5 or Retina Display

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, retina-display, iphone-5, autoresize

[image: Tabbar Issue in Retina or iPhone5 Screen]

I have used tabbar controller using storyboard in application with iOS 6.

In normal or iPhone-4, Screen Layouts are fine. But in iPhone-5 or Retina display, I am stuck with Tabbar Controller layout..:(

Any Specific settings for this? Please tell me solution ASAP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402803/developing-fullscreen-4inch-app-in-xcode that should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me at least.

Code ::

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 519, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
}
else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
{
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
}
```